# yii2 htmlhelper dropdownlist values

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have an array as below:

```
array[$key][$value]
```

and I am using it to form a dropDownList in my view. I am not using ActiveForm because the array is not from a model.

```
echo Html::dropDownList("Listname","",$array,['prompt' => '--- select ---']) ;
echo Html::dropDownList("Listname","",ArrayHelper::map($array,'id','value'),['prompt' => '--- select ---']) ;
```

Var_dump

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "value1" [1]=> string(6) "value2" [3]...}
```

The output html looks something like this

```
<select name="Listname" >
<option value>---select---</option
<option value="0">Value1</option>
<option value="1">Value2</option>
<option value="2">Value3</option>
<option value="3">Value4</option>
</select>
```

How do I set the values to be = to the name? such as

```
<option value="value1">Value1</option>
<option value="value2">Value2</option>
<option value="value3">Value3</option>
<option value="value4">Value4</option>
```

I realize i probably have to use ArrayHelper somehow, but I just can't quite get it. That, or the option tags in the htmlhelper.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `ArrayHelper::map($array,'value','value')`

Comment: Hi i edited in my var_dump of the array. will map still work in this case? 
i will try to reformat my array and test it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
echo Html::dropDownList("Listname","",ArrayHelper::map($array,'id','value'),['prompt' => '--- select ---']) ;
```

If you want the same value for each input as its content, it should be:

```
echo Html::dropDownList("Listname","",ArrayHelper::map($array,'value','value'),['prompt' => '--- select ---']) ;
```

For more info, take a look at the official ArrayHelper::map documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#map()-detail

You have to keep in mind that Html::dropDownList is expecting a key=>value array, how you get that array doesn't matter. I mean, ArrayHelper is just, as the name suggest, a helper. You can build your array by your own if you feel more confortable.

Comment: Thanks! I believe my array is not in proper order. I will test it out with a new array